# Malformed entry Ubu

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have searched these forums and found them helpful in the past, however, I can't seem to find a viable option for my problem. When I try to apt-get update (Ubuntu bionic 18), I get the following:

```
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rehinkdb.list (type)
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list (Component)

E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I have tried lsb-release with no success. I appreciate any help from your expertise. Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322782/malformed-entry-ubu/) by [jrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/41290/jrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2019-05-09**:
Is this only happen when installing ROS?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-09**:
What is the output of:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

> I have tried lsb-release with no success.

What do you mean exactly by this? Does `lsb_release -c` not output anything, or do you not have the program installed?

if the latter: that could be the cause of those two files containing malformed entries (as some information is missing that `lsb_release` would provide).

**Comment by [jrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/41290/jrock/) on 2019-05-09**:
gvdhoorn the output is

```
deb http:packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu main
```

lsb_release -c outputs

```
Codename:       bionic
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your apt sources.list content is malformed, you are missing the `distribution` name

Here's a reference for the file format: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

It should be of the form `deb http://site.example.com/debian distribution component1 component2 component3`

So if you change it to

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main
```

It should work.

Based on the above error message I would guess that you have the same problem with your `rethinkdb.list` file too

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/41290/jrock/) on 2019-05-09**:
tfoote did I download a corrupt package on the upgrade? Here is what I got:

```
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic main

Command 'deb' not found, did you mean:



 command 'den' from snap den (1.2.0-0)
  command 'dub' from snap dub (1.14.0)
  command 'debc' from deb devscripts
  command 'derb' from deb icu-devtools
  command 'edb' from deb edb-debugger
  command 'dex' from deb dex
  command 'dep' from deb go-dep
  command 'dub' from deb dub
  command 'dab' from deb bsdgames
  command 'debi' from deb devscripts
  command 'xdeb' from deb xdeb
  command 'deb3' from deb quilt
```

See 'snap info ' for additional versions

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-10**:
`deb` is not a command. It's the first word that should appear on the line in the `.list` files.

**Comment by [jrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/41290/jrock/) on 2019-05-11**:
Thank you. That solved the problem.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-05-11**:
Please use the checkbox at left to accept the answer so people know your question is solved.